# Flutter SDK not matching in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I am having some errors with my flutter project as seen below.
I tried flutter upgrade, flutter clean, nothing is working to solve this issue.

**Output from flutter pub get:**

```
flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in demo_app_1...                      
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

Because demo_app_1 depends on cloud_firestore >=3.1.10 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because demo_app_1 depends on cloud_firestore >=3.1.10 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

*flutter --version* in terminal :

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.847 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7459332538 (61 minutes ago) • 2022-05-21 02:33:07 -0400
Engine • revision 0264282e8b
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-139.0.dev) • DevTools 2.13.1\
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in the pubspec.yaml you define the flutter sdk version (detailed information see here: [Flutter and the pubspec file](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec))

your importent part is the

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

here you define the sdk version and like the error message says, cloud_firestore requires a SDK version between 2.16.0 and 3.0.0

so you have to adjust these version to reach the requirements